# Unable to get value of textbox in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using `jquery 1.9.1.js` and `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js`. I run on IE9 browser with the error `"Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or undefined"`. Below is my code.

```
  $("input[id^='TextBoxAssociate']").autocomplete(
        {
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "CreateEditRequest.aspx/GetEmpNames",
                    data: "{'empName':'" + $(this).val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (el) {
                            return {
                                label: el.EmpName,
                                value: el.EmpId
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
```

When I comment  `response($.map(data.d, function (el) { ... }` part then there is not error and not output. There could be issue in versioning or browser compatability. I tried in ie8 also. Also check by adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

But not work for me and showing above message in title.

Error IS here in  jquery.1.9.1.js

```
val: function( value ) {
    var ret, hooks, isFunction,
        elem = this[0];
    if ( !arguments.length ) {
        if ( elem ) {
            hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

            if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && (ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" )) !== undefined ) {
                return ret;
            }
            ret = elem.value;
            return typeof ret === "string" ?
                // handle most common string cases
                ret.replace(rreturn, "") :
                // handle cases where value is null/undef or number
                ret == null ? "" : ret;
        }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: The error in your title does not occur anywhere in the code you posted (you do not call toLowerCase). Can you post the code of the response function or the error location as reported by a javascript debugger?

Comment: What's the response from `CreateEditRequest.aspx/GetEmpNames?empName=John` ?

Comment: @acdcjunior : It is giving me an error `Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined`

Comment: Actually, my mistake, your code is not performing a `GET`, it is performing a `POST`. Can you verify if the response of a `POST` to `CreateEditRequest.aspx/GetEmpNames` with `empName=John` is returning a JSON array of employees, like: `'[{"EmpName":"John Nash","EmpId":1},{"EmpName":"John Smith","EmpId":2}]'` ?

Comment: I found problem is with `$(this).val()` statement which is undefined. How can i get textbox value which suppose to pass to page method?

Comment: Oh, then change it to: `data: "{'empName':'" + request.term + "'}",`

Comment: thanks boss. You save my day :)

Comment: Great! I'm gonna add it as an answer so other can solve the same problem in the future, ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [jQuery UI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), the `this` will not hold a reference to the related `input`. It probably will hold a reference to the newly created function, but this is undocumented.

To achieve what you want, you have two options:

#### If you just want the text typed on the input

Then, and this is [documented](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), use `request.term` (it is a string):

```
$("input[id^='TextBoxAssociate']").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            // ...
            data: "{'empName':'" + request.term + "'}", // <--------------------
            // ...
        });
    });
```

#### If you want the actual element bound to the `autocomplete`

In this case you'll have to hold the element in a variable external to the `.autocomplete()` call.

As `"input[id^='TextBoxAssociate']"` will probably return several elements, you'll have to use an `.each()` loop:

```
$("input[id^='TextBoxAssociate']").each(function () {
    var myElement = $(this);
    myElement.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            // ...
            data: "{'empName':'" + myElement.val() + "'}", // <-----------------
            // ...
        });
    }
});
```

In this approach, the other jQuery functions, such as `.attr()` and else, will be available to `myElement` as usual.

Comment: Great this is perfect as what i want.

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior ! I have been looking for such option. You made my day :)